# Where to find list of packages that are installed during upgrade to 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, but the update crashed with the "Something has gone wrong" screen. I figured I could fix it by going to the TTY, and it did seem to fix it. I am now running Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.

I ran several update commands and everything is in order. But, there are clearly some packages that I need to install, and they weren't installed when I resumed the upgrade. For example, I had to install `power-profiles-daemon` to get the new Jammy Jellyfish power options (saver, balanced, and performance), and the package would have never been installed if I hadn't realized that I didn't have those settings yet.

This tells me that there are definately more packages that haven't been installed and that my system isn't going to try and install. Where can I find a list of all packages I need, so I can try to get them? Maybe do a massive `sudo apt install <lots of packages>` and it will install the ones I don't have?

Comment: The list is over a thousand packages, so let apt run through that list for you. For most users recovering from a failed upgrade, a simple `sudo apt dist-upgrade` then `sudo dpkg configure -a` then `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo snap refresh` will complete the aborted upgrade...when the system is recoverable at all. Read your output carefully before agreeing to package changes. Stop if you encounter errors.

Comment: @user535733 I did those commands when I was in TTY, and they don't do anything different right now.

Comment: Next step: Review your /var/log/apt/history.log. That will list, among other events, all packages removed by apt during the release-upgrade.

Comment: @user535733 Seems like it cleared that file since the upgrade. I'm only seeing logs from after the upgrade.

Comment: That log rotates monthly. Older logs are in the same directory.

Comment: @user535733 Do you know where to find a list of packages so I can see if they are all installed (i know there are like 2,000)

Comment: Sure: Try https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest for the 22.04.1 desktop stock install manifest. Browsing the directories will get you different release. Apt uses a different methodology to arrive at its conclusions during a release-upgrade; there is no list for that, but the end result will be very, very close.